# Extraction one sign from string

Tags: c, string, char

How can i extract only one char from the string
`string [9] = "something";` and i would like to write down only one sign
lets say "t"

Comment: I propose you make yourself comfortable with the concept of "Array" and how to address its elements via an index.

Comment: String is array by itself in C. `&string[4]`

Comment: `string[4]`. Also `string [9] = "something";` --> `string [] = "something";`